# Word usage of "type in"

Tags: word-usage, word-difference

Which phrase should I use in this sentence?

please type in your file name.
or 
Please type your file name.

Comment: In "please type **in** your file name", what does "in" point to? You didn't say, so just use "please type your file name". An example with in might be "Please type/enter your file name *in* the box labelled "file name".

Answer (score 1):

If this is for a PC application, you should not use *type* at all because you don't really know what input device the user will use to enter the characters - it could be a physical keyboard, onscreen keyboard, or even voice control.

Use the verb *enter*.

Comment: When can I use "type"? When I use a keyboard to enter something?

Comment: "type" usually refers to a typewriter. You could use it for computer keyboards, but nowadays it is unlikely especially for technically proficient users.